# How to Allow AWS Lambda to access RDS Data API in Java SAM offline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sam, rds-data-api

I am trying to access my Aurora Serverless DB from an AWS Lambda function I am developing using SAM and Java 8. I have added the appropriate policies to the template.yaml file. When I try to execute the Lambda offline using sam local invoke, I get:

```
"errorMessage":"The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AWSRDSData; Status Code: 403; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException
```

When I deploy the application and run the Lambda from the console, everything runs just fine.

Also, I tried mirroring the function in Python using the same policies in the template.yaml file, everything worked fine both offline and deployed.

Is there something else I need to do in Java to make this work offline?

Comment: Are you doing anything in your code that is referring to the Access Key and Secret Key credentials? If so, please show us that portion of your code.

Comment: What do you mean by accessing it "offline"? You have to be able to access AWS to use its services.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am not using anything referring to the Access Key and Secret Key.

Comment: @Marcin By offline, I mean running locally with sam local invoke

Comment: There is a minor chance for this, but... Can you check whether the Date, Time & Region on your computer is accurate? If it drifts too far from correct time, then the request signature will be denied.